# Sort pivot table by groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm struggling with the usage of pivot tables for pandas.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: Company name, date and number of orders.

I'm trying to pivot the dataframe in such a way that I'd be able to see top 10 biggest customers.

So for example, lets say I have

```
name | date | orders
John | 2017 | 100
John | 2018 | 200
John | 2019 | 300
Mary | 2017 | 50
Mary | 2018 | 50
Mary | 2019 | 1000
```

I want to pivot this in a way where I'd be able to see it like this

```
name
date  2017 | 2018 | 2019
John  100  | 200  | 300
Mary  50   | 50   | 1000
```

And sorted by total amount of orders, so in this case, Mary should go first because she has 1100 orders in total.

I cannot do the sorting in groups, it's outputting Mary 1000 1st, John 300 2nd and John 200 3rd (to give an example)

Also, maybe a bit unrelated but I also noticed that when pivoting, it's throwing the results in scientfic notation (despite the df displaying the numbers without it) and if I disable SciNot, it's converting the values to floats, any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: The link does not cover how to sort the pivots at all

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_out = df.pivot('name','date')['orders']
df_out = df_out.assign(sortkey = df_out.sum(axis=1))\
               .sort_values('sortkey', ascending=False)\
               .drop('sortkey', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
date  2017  2018  2019
name                  
Mary    50    50  1000
John   100   200   300
```